# Can python black formatter use tabulators instead of spaces?

Tags: python, python-black

I want to use the **python black** code reformatter in my pre-commit hooks, but in my company they decided to use tabulators in python code instead of spaces.
So I tried to change blacks configuration, but I haven't seen any option to use tabulators, only thing you can influence in is the line length.

Is black so tightly bound to the PEP8 standard that it will never allow tabulators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible. The Python Black supports only the spaces.

Here is a ticket for it: https://github.com/psf/black/issues/47 (It contains a conversation why Python Black won't support the tabs).

As they said when they closed the ticket:

> No, tabs for indentation are the devil. Making this configurable would
>   go against Black's philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

If Black won't give you an option just post-process the result...

```
import sys, pathlib, re

def spaces2tabs(t):
    while True:
        t, n = re.subn('^(\t*) {4}', '\\1\t', t, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        if not n: return t

p = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1])
p.write_text(spaces2tabs(p.read_text()))
```