# How can I use tabs for indentation and not getting pylint warnings in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

So, I've seen that this issue comes up a lot, but it seems the solutions provided are not working for me... Pylint do not seem to get that I want tabs for indent, with a width of 4 spaces.

I've created a simple script to try this out:

```py
def one_fun():
    print("hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    one_fun()
```

Here's my `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
}
```

which also contains what I've seen proposing as solution here and there (just [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118651/how-to-set-python-language-specific-tab-spacing-in-visual-studio-code)).

I wanted to have **pylint** as linter and **black** as formatter, but it seems I'm missing something and this comes up (pointer is on the warning to show the automatic message)
[image]

If I convert indentations to spaces, using the top right bar, everything disappears and **pylint** is happy, it seems.
Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Wait, it's hard to tell from the screenshot, when you press tab, is vscode actually insert a tab character or 4 spaces?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's a tab. see the `->` whitespace indicator? spaces have dots as their whitespace indicators in VS Code, and tabs have `->`. What I find weird is that slim71 has `"editor.insertSpaces": true,` in their Python language settings, which should mean that the tab key inserts spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Actually, slim71, I'm getting mixed signals from your post. Do you want indentation with tabs or with spaces? You say "_Pylint do not seem to get that I want tabs for indent, with a width of 4 spaces_", which makes me think you want tabs, but you put `"editor.insertSpaces": true,` in your settings, and then even more confusing is the fact that you then go on to say "_If I convert indentations to spaces_", which you shouldn't need to do if you've set `"editor.insertSpaces": true,`. What's going on?

Comment: @user I see, so the question is why isn't the configuration in the settings.json reflected in the editor? but it seems the OP *does* want tabs, so I'm confused

Comment: @user yes, that is my confusion as well!

Comment: In any case, pylint **wants you to use spaces**. Not tabs. It wants 4 spaces. I guess if you want to change that then maybe pylint is configurable in that regard

Comment: sorry everybody, I guess I was not clear enough! 
I want tabs, since I prefer them. The "width" is just to indicate that visually I'd like a tab to occupy the same as 4 spaces
@user you're right: it is indeed misleading, sorry!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that, I wasn't aware of!
is the same valid for flake8 then? because I've tried switching and it does more or less the same (saying "indentation contains tab").... Maybe I lack this kind of knowledge, since I've was under the assumption that tabs/spaces are the same for Python, in the end... should I switch to spaces then?

Comment: @slim71 yes, this is the official python Python convention, according to PEP8

Comment: then I guess I wasted time trying to solve the wrong problem here... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is ["bad-indentation (W0311)"](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/bad-indentation.html). Since you *want* tabs, your `"editor.insertSpaces": true,` should instead be `"editor.insertSpaces": false,`, and to make pylint accept your usage of tabs for indentation, you need to put the following in a `.pylintrc` file in the root of your workspace folder:

```
[FORMAT]
indent-string=\t
```

See also https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#indent-string.

You can also disable the Pylint warning as shown in another answer post here, but I think that's a bad solution, since presumably it will mean you won't get warnings if you then use indentation which is *not* tabs.

As for using tabs with Black as your formatter, it seems that that's not possible. See [Can python black formatter use tabulators instead of spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135128/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you've got what you expect: tabs with a width of 4. It's just that pylint treats a tab as a space and raises a warning.

If you want to press <kbd>Tap</kbd> to insert *spaces* instead of *tabs*, then change `"editor.insertSpaces": true,` to `"editor.insertSpaces": false,`.

Of course, it is more convenient to click **Tab Size: *** displayed in the lower right corner of the interface, and then make a selection.

[image]

[image]

You can also add the following settings to eliminate such errors in pylint.

```json
    // If you use the pylint extension
    "pylint.args": [
        "--disable=W0311"
    ],
    // If you use the pylint package
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=W0311"
    ]
```